# unexpected change of wchar variable

Tags: c++, directx

Okey this is driving me crazy now...

I'm working on a directX game in c++ and I got a global wchar variable called FpsString witch i declared like this:

```
WCHAR * FpsString;
```

And in my initialization code i initialized it like this:

```
WCHAR a[100];  
FpsString = a;
```

Okay, here is the prob... FpsString suddenly changes to some Japanese (no offense) letters every time I enter the Render loop

Did I declare it wrong or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `WCHAR a[100];` also global (static) or is it perhaps a local variable?

If it's local then that's your problem: It stops to exist when the scope (function) is complete.
Change it to `FpsString = new WCHAR[100];`